# Vuforia Rajawali Android - How to build the gradle in git?

Tags: vuforia, rajawali

I'm new to VuforiaRajawali and I'm trying to build and run the example from the site. The problem is when I'm using the command:

C:/.../RajawaliVuforia/RajawaliVuforia/  ./gradlew clean assembleRelease uploadArchives

, I'm always getting the error task 'clean' not found in root project RajawaliVuforia.

If it's possible, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guessed that You are using a windows 
so
Try the following after installing [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

1- Create a new folder.
2- Enter the created folder then hold Shift Key+ Right click in an EMPTY AREA.
3- select "Open command window here" from the appearing context menu.
4- type or copy pasting the command "git clone https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVuforia.git"
5- Press enter and wait while the git cloning Rajawali.
6- Right Click to (This PC) for windows 8 or above (Computer or My Computer)windows 7 and select Properties.
7- from the left panel select Advanced system settings.
8- from the popped up window click "Environment Variables..." at the bottom.
9- at the top of the new popped window under User variables for [user name]
click on New... and type in
variable name: "ANDROID_HOME".
variable value: [the full Path to android SDK]
10- go the the created folder you will found a folder with name "RajawaliVuforia"
Open it   again you will found 3 folders and one has the same name "RajawaliVuforia" Open it and while press Shift Key Right click on an Empty Area and from the context menu select "Open command window here"
write or paste the command "gradlew clean assembleRelease uploadArchives" Press enter.
11- wait for the command to end
 Now you Are Done you can open the project using android studio